# php currency take

Tags: php, numbers, currency

I need to know how to take

> 10.25 and turn it to 1025

basically it needs to remove full stop from any number for e.g.
1500.25 it should be 150025

Comment: Is `1500.25` a float or a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$number = str_replace('.','',$number);
```

Comment: str_replace will work, but what if his value is 10.3567 (for example, an average cost)? The answer below (multiply by 100 and cast to int) will work no matter what the input is.

Comment: This is really dangerous if $number is a floating-point value. What happens if the float cannot exactly describe the value and a few more decimal places appears? And what happens if the value is `1500.3`?

Comment: @Fluffeh, @Emil Vikström. We can't realy solve op's **problem**, cause we can not know what the problem is. What we can is just answer the **question**. The question was: `how to take 10.25 and turn it to 1025`, so the answer is to use `str_replace` and it will work here. And we can't be responsible if the question doesn't match the problem

Comment: k102, you are of course correct! You deserve my upvote for answering the question. In the question as asked, `10.3567` will of course turn into `103567` when "removing the full stop".

Answer (score 2):

if the currency is a float: multiply with 100 (and cast the result to `int`).

```
$currency = 10.25;
$number = (int)($currency * 100); //1025
```

note that this solution will only get the first two decimals saved - if you have a number like `10.123`, the `3` will simply be cut off without rounding.

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic should be avoided when handling values which needs to be exact (money handling must always be exact).

Comment: you're absolutely right, but if it's a floating-point number before, you're already potentially fu**ed up as something else might be calculated using that. if you want to be exact, use real number everywhere and only make floating-points out of this for displaying - but this clearly isn't the case here as there shouldn't be any reason to cast back.

Comment: But do we know that it's a float value to start with? It may be a string in which case your solution casts it into a float. I think this is the best solution if $currency already is a float (I did almost post the exact same answer), but if it's in fact a string you should do string work.

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point arithmetic is by it's definition not exact. Therefore it's worthwhile to NOT cast the value to a float if it's a string, and avoid casting it into a string if it's a float.

Here's a function which takes care to check the value type:

```
function toCents($value) {
  // Strings with a dot is specially handled
  // so they won't be converted to float
  if (is_string($value) && strpos($value, '.') !== false) {
    list($integer, $decimals) = explode('.', $value);
    $decimals = (int) substr($decimals . '00', 0, 2);
    return ((int) $integer) * 100 + $decimals;

  // float values are rounded to avoid errors when a value
  // like ".10" is saved as ".099"
  } elseif (is_float($value) {
    return round($value * 100);

  // Other values are strings or integers, which are cast
  // to int and multiplied directly.
  } else {
    return ((int) $value) * 100;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want replace one character only, use strtr instead str_replace

```
$number = str_replace('.','',$number);
```

and

```
$number = strtr($number, array('.', ''));
```

same output but strtr is better.